# Setting layout in code or the GUI designer doesn't work for JPanel. Layout is always FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I used the IntelliJ GUI Designer to create a `JPanel`.  It has three `JButtons` that are stacked vertically.  When I run the code it has the three `JButtons` side by side, like it is using FlowLayout.  FlowLayout is the default layout for a `JPanel`.  I have tried setting the layout manager to various layouts in the GUI Designer and in the code.  It always looks like the FlowLayout.  How can I use a different layout with a `JPanel`?  I would like to use the designer's GridLayoutManager.

Here is the java code:

```
public class myJPanelTest extends JPanel
{
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;

    public myJPanelTest()
    {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        add(button1);
        add(button2);
        add(button3);
    }  
}
```

Here is the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/" version="1" bind-to-class="abc.dfg.tbs.CM.myJPanelTest">
  <grid id="27dc6" layout-manager="GridLayoutManager" row-count="3" column-count="2" same-size-horizontally="false" same-size-vertically="false" hgap="-1" vgap="-1">
    <margin top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0"/>
    <constraints>
      <xy x="20" y="20" width="500" height="400"/>
    </constraints>
    <properties/>
    <border type="none"/>
    <children>
      <component id="c8918" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="button1" default-binding="true">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="2" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <text value="Button 1"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <vspacer id="8e9eb">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="1" column="1" row-span="2" col-span="1" vsize-policy="6" hsize-policy="1" anchor="0" fill="2" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
      </vspacer>
      <component id="dff25" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="button2" default-binding="true">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="1" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <text value="Button 2"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <component id="ac93b" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="button3" default-binding="true">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="2" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <text value="Button 3"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
    </children>
  </grid>
</form>
```

How can I stop the layout from only using FlowLayout for a `JPanel`?

Comment: `I would like to use the designer's GridLayoutManager.` - I would suggest you learn how to code the layouts by hand instead of using a GUI designer. Then you don't spend time learning the designer and the code is portable if you ever need to change the tool. In other words spend time learning Swing not the tool. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples of doing the code yourself.

Comment: I inherited this code from a co-worker and our boss wants this fixed without taking the time to learn how to code layouts by hand.